# JQuery Selector Question?

Tags: jquery

How can change the following JQuery code so I can use class selectors instead of id selectors so I can use class="add" and class="container" instead of id="add" and id="container"

Here is the JQuery code.

```
  $(function(){
      $('a#add').click(function(){
        $('#container').slideToggle('slow');
        // prevent default action
        return false;
      });
    });
```

**I got it to work thanks everyone for the help.**

Comment: @Ionut Staicu everyone has to learn selectors sooner or later man.

Comment: @Kyle: the natural order is: learn css/html THEN learn js/a js library. Besides that, is right on the jquery page: http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_item_using_class_or_id.3F 

But hey, I'm Mr obvious! @alpha: what's the difference on reading here, on SO or reading there, on jQuery page?

Answer (score 3):

JS

```
$('a.add').click(function(){ // Use . (dot) for class select
    $('.container').slideToggle('slow');
    return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="add">Add container</a>
<div class="container">
  My container content
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

use a . not a #

Comment: And by the way, Using IDs isn't bad, it's actually a much quicker selector then classes, plus there could be the issue of having two classes and one shouldn't be animated.

Comment: Are you sure they are classes in HTML? Did you load jQuery? Is slideToggle an existing function?

lol you need to put up more code so I can get some context as to what your issue is. Could be that you're using a $(function() { instead of a $(document).ready(function() { to begin with.

Comment: It works with the id selectors but not with the class selectors:(

Comment: Then why not just use the ID tags? =)